# Move element before the end of BODY

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to place an html element just before my body end tag, without knowing which tags are before it? In this scenario i don't know that there is a `ul` list at the end.

**Note**: I can't use jquery to solve this.

e.g.

```
<body>
   <p id="test">Hello</p>

   <script>
       document.getElementById("test").MOVE_BEFORE_BODY();   //<-- something like this
   </script>

   <ul>
     <li>...</li>
     <li>some random stuff</li>
   </ul>
   <!-- element should be moved to this position -->
</body>
```

Comment: `document.body.appendChild(myElement);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`someElement.appendChild` will move an element to the end of `someElement`.

```
document.body.appendChild(
    document.getElementById("test")
);
```

Comment: Works perfect!:) There is a missing `"` tho.

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.body.appendChild(yourElement)`